# Stuck on probability/statistics question

Tags: probability, statistics

EDIT: Post as been edited to address relevant questions raised in comments.

I'm new to the site and I'm stuck on a probability question.  I don't think it's trivial, certainly not to me, as I am relying on a single probability and statistics class I took 20 years ago...  The problem is this:

- Imagine there are 10 white squares (the number of white squares is not terribly important other than it has to be 5 or greater).
- The probability of turning a white square black is 25% per attempt.
- The goal is to maximize the number of black squares you get.
- You have 10 "moves" to do so.
- Attempting to turn a white square black uses one move.
- Moving from one square to another also uses one move.
- You send in your "moves" in batches of 10 and, therefore, you cannot adjust subsequent moves regardless of the results of previous moves.
- Attempting to convert a square that you had previously successfully converted from white to black does not revert it back to white. It just means you wasted a move trying to convert an already black square.

How would I even start figuring out the best way to maximize the number of black squares I get (i.e., how many attempts per square before moving to the next square)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Why would you move to a new square before you had successfully converted the one you are on?  Isn't it better to just keep trying the one you are on until you get it to change, and then move on to the next?

Comment: I agree with @lulu.  Moving to another square uses up a move that would be better spent trying to change the color.

Comment: Thank you.  Definitely worth clarifying.  You send in your desired moves in batches of 10 and you do not know the results of the attempts to convert the squares until the end of the 10 moves.  Therefore, if you just attempt to convert your square and do nothing else, you will likely have wasted moved.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity and completeness.  For instance:  what happens if you try to change a black square?

Comment: Another good point, lulu.  Thanks.  Just updated it.

Comment: And what have you tried? Consider the optimistic strategy;  Try the first one, move, try the second, move.  I Guess this means you try the fifth one twice.  Then you expect to get about  $1.438$ black squares.  Do you have a strategy that does better than that?

Comment: I guess you do slightly better if you try the first one $4$ times, move, and then try the second one $5$ times.  If I haven't miscalculated, with that one you expect to get $(1-.75^4)+(1-.75^5)=1.446289063$ which is slightly greater than the $1.4375$ that you get with the optimistic strategy.  What about just trying three as often as you can?

Comment: In any case, I would  compare strategies like this.  There is a high cost to moving, so I think it makes sense to linger a bit on each square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn’t specify a geometry, so I’ll assume that we can always move to a fresh square.

You say you want to maximize the number of black squares, but that’s not a meaningful objective since this is a random variable. I’ll assume that you in fact want to maximize the *expected* number of black squares.

Your terminology is a bit confusing, since you’re using “move” with two different meanings; so I’ll call the moves “turns” instead.

It certainly makes sense to try each square once before moving on, and it makes no sense to move on the last turn. So we should never move more than $4$ times.

Given a number of moves from $0$ to $4$, it’s clear that we should distribute the attempts over the squares as equally as possible.

That yields $5$ inequivalent strategies: $(10)$, $(5,4)$, $(3,3,2)$, $(2,2,2,1)$ and $(2,1,1,1,1)$, with expected numbers of black squares

\begin{eqnarray}
1-\left(\frac34\right)^{10}=\frac{989527}{1048576}&\approx&0.94369\;,\\
1-\left(\frac34\right)^5+1-\left(\frac34\right)^4=\frac{1481}{1024}&\approx&1.44629\;,\\
2\left(1-\left(\frac34\right)^3\right)+1-\left(\frac34\right)^2=\frac{51}{32}&=&1.59375\;,\\
3\left(1-\left(\frac34\right)^2\right)+1-\left(\frac34\right)^1=\frac{25}{16}&=&1.5625\;,\\
1-\left(\frac34\right)^2+4\left(1-\left(\frac34\right)^1\right)=\frac{23}{16}&=&1.4375\;,\\
\end{eqnarray}

respectively, so the optimal strategy is to move twice, trying two squares thrice and one square twice, with an expected number $\frac{51}{32}$ of black squares.

Comment: Thank you all and joriki for your thoughtful answer. As I expected, I was out of my depth so this is much appreciated!